# Xamarin Modal Page Transition to Normal Page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Xamarin is having default page transition animation. Modal Page from bottom to top and Normal Page from right to left. Is there a way to apply modal page transition animation to a normal page.

I tried various CATransition animation in iOS using NavigationPageRenderer. I am not able to match the exact modal page animation provided by xamarin default.

```
protected override Task<bool> OnPushAsync(Page page, bool animated)
    {
        var type = page.GetType();
        if (Startup.Instance.ModalPages.Contains(type))
        {
            var transition = CATransition.CreateAnimation();
            transition.Duration = 0.5f;
            transition.Type = CAAnimation.TransitionMoveIn; //tried other animation transitions
            transition.Subtype = CAAnimation.TransitionFromTop;
            View.Layer.AddAnimation(transition, null);
            return base.OnPushAsync(page, false);
        }
        else
        {
            return base.OnPushAsync(page, animated);
        }
    }

    protected override Task<bool> OnPopViewAsync(Page page, bool animated)
    {
        var type = page.GetType();
        if (Startup.Instance.ModalPages.Contains(type))
        {
            var transition = CATransition.CreateAnimation();
            transition.Duration = 0.5f;
            transition.Type = CAAnimation.TransitionReveal;
            transition.Subtype = CAAnimation.TransitionFromBottom;
            View.Layer.AddAnimation(transition, null);
            return base.OnPopViewAsync(page, false);
        }
        else
        {
            return base.OnPopViewAsync(page, animated);
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi , it seems that Modal Page is not related to `NavigationPageRenderer` , that belongs to `PageRenderer` . You can have a try with `PageRenderer` whether can achieve that .There is a `modalTransitionStyle` in Apple doc .(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621465-presentmodalviewcontroller?language=occ)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to apply modal page transition animation to a normal page.

If just want to keep the same **TransitionStyle**  with navigation of normal page. You  can hide the `NavigationBar` when `PushAsync` , and not need to use `PushModelAsync` .

For example ,  `Button_Clicked` method of **MainPage** as follow :

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Navigation.PushAsync(new PageTwo());
}
```

Then **PageTwo** :

```
public partial class PageTwo : ContentPage
{
    public PageTwo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
}
```

The effect should be your want :

[image]

============================Update===================================

If need to use **PushModelAsync** , there is a workaround to achieve that effect .

Create a **CustomPageRenderer** for PageTwo in iOS solution :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PageTwo), typeof(CustomPageRenderer))]
namespace XamarinMoelNavigationStyle.iOS
{
    public class CustomPageRenderer :PageRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            var transition = CATransition.CreateAnimation();
            transition.Duration = 0.5f;
            transition.Type = CAAnimation.TransitionPush;
            transition.Subtype = CAAnimation.TransitionFromRight;
            View.Layer.AddAnimation(transition, null);

            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        }

    }
}
```

We will add animation inside `ViewWillAppear` method .

When poping to previous `MainPage` , we can deal with that in ContentPage as follow :

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    PageTwoView.TranslateTo(300, 0, 500);

    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), () =>
    {
        // Do something

        Navigation.PopModalAsync(false);

        return false; // True = Repeat again, False = Stop the timer
    });

}
```

Here `PageTwoView` is defined from Xaml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Name="PageTwoView"
             x:Class="XamarinMoelNavigationStyle.PageTwo">
     ...
</ContentPage>
```

Note : When `MainPage` navigate to `PageTwo` , need to disable the animation .

Such as :

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PageTwo(), false);
}
```

The effect :

[image]

Comment: Can this be applied for a custom Android render as well? Any idea how?